# Primeng: p-calender default date not working

Tags: angular, typescript, primeng

I need to set a default date in datepicker. I tried using defaultDate property of p-calender as given below:

```
<p-calendar placeholder="mm/dd/yyyy"
name="deadline" 
required 
[(ngModel)]="deadline" 
#deadline="ngModel" 
[showIcon]="true" 
showTime="showTime" 
hourFormat="12"
[defaultDate]="defaultDate">
```

Component.ts code:

```
public defaultDate: Date = new Date();
ngOnInit() {
    this.defaultDate.setDate(this.defaultDate.getDate() - 5);
}
```

However, the above code is not working. Please help.

Answer (score 2):

```
//deadline: Date = new Date(0);
deadline: Date;
defaultDate: Date = new Date("January 31 1980 12:30");

ngOnInit() {
   //if (this.deadline == undefined)
   //    this.deadline = new Date("June 30 1966 12:30");
}
```

According to the [issue](https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/issues/2799), defaultDate is to display the month-year on first opening if the field is blank.

The defaultDate property is not used to set a specific date and is only applicable if ngModel value is not set. To set the default displayed date, use ngModel instead of defaultDate.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use ngModel for binding with your default date as described here : [Open Link](https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/issues/2799)

So, in your case, something like this should work:

```
<p-calendar placeholder="mm/dd/yyyy"
name="deadline" 
required 
[(ngModel)]="deadline" 
#deadline="ngModel" 
[showIcon]="true" 
showTime="showTime" 
hourFormat="12"
[defaultDate]=deadline>
```

Please refer to calendar.ts file for more information in Primeng github: https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/blob/master/src/app/components/calendar/calendar.ts

Comment: You seem to have two [(ngModel)] attributes in your tag

Comment: Just corrected that, it should be binding to the defaultDate input property of Calendar component

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
public deadline: Date;
ngOnInit() {
    this.deadline.setDate((new Date()).getDate() - 5);
}
```