# How to show the enabled dates directly in p-calender

Tags: angular5, primeng, primeng-calendar

I have an input field that uses the  component. Say I have disabled the dates till 15th May. When I click on the calender, the current month is shown as April and all dates in it are disabled. How can I make the current month as the one that doesn't have disabled dates? (May month in this case)

Comment: Please provide a working stackblitz example, or add some code here.

Answer (score 0):

Use `defaultDate` to display the current month you want to first display. The `defaultDate` is only applicable if `ngModel` is not initially set. See similar issue ([Primeng: p-calender default date not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46932331/primeng-p-calender-default-date-not-working/49568820#49568820)).

```
<p-calendar [(ngModel)]="startDate" [disabledDates]="invalidDates" [defaultDate]="defaultDate" showIcon="true"></p-calendar>
```

[**Stackblitz example**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/issue-primeng-invalid-dates)